# Allow space with alphanumeric rule in jQuery Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validator alpha numeric rule but i want to allow space but right now the issue is when i give space it shows error, my main requirement is i don't want user to enter special characters ore symbols in text fields, my code is like this:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

> Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
        $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                field: {
                    required: true,
                    alphanumeric: true
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
                return false; // for demo
            }
        });
    
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom **validator** method and specify your custom validation there.Whenever user clicked on submit button this will get called and will validate the input according to the rules defined in it .

In below code i have use regex to match user input . i.e :

`^` : It represents start of string . 
`\w` : It matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
  (space or ) `\s` : It matches any space, tab or newline character.
`$` : It represent end of string .
`.test(value)` :It match between a regular expression and a specified string and return true or false.

***Demo code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //add this custom methid
  $.validator.addMethod("alphanumeric", function(value, element) {
    //test user value with the regex
    return this.optional(element) || /^[\w ]+$/i.test(value);
  }, "Letters, numbers only please");

  $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
    rules: {
      field: {
        required: true,
        alphanumeric: true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
      alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
      return false; // for demo
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js
"></script>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="field" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```